# Is it possible to use a TypeScript union type in TypeORM?

Tags: typescript, typeorm

Is it possible for a TypeORM entity to have a field that consists of multiple different types? In pure TypeScript I would create what I want, like this:

```
type CustomType = Workout | Photo

interface Day {
    events: CustomType[]
}
```

I want something like this in TypeORM (this example doesn't work):

```
@Entity()
class Day {
    @OneToMany(() => CustomType, customType => customType.day)
    events: CustomType[]
}
```

My question is, is there support for a union type in TypeORM?

Comment: Asking the same thing, were you able to solve this?